# AngularJS - How to apply currency filter on textbox as I type?

Tags: angularjs, string-formatting, angularjs-filter

My project has a requirement to show amount field in currency format. I can achieve this `onblur` event, but let me know if this can be achieved using filters or some other AngularJS technique.

I have the following textbox:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="MyAmount" name="MyAmount" ng-model="MyAmount" />
```

I want to convert the value inside this text box to follow currency format. So, if I type 200000, it should make is $200,000.00 as soon as I type or while I am typing.

I used the following technique and applied a filter,

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="MyAmount" name="MyAmount" ng-model="MyAmount"
                            value="{{MyAmount | currency}}" />
```

but it only converts for the first key I type, like it converts 2 to $2.00 and then it clears the value (as I guess it finds this updated value as not a number?)

Update: I am able to format it live using a custom filter, but that filter is not working properly in all the cases and when I save the value, I am getting values with $ and commas in the amount and not just the numeric value. I will try more.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a rather non-trivial problem.
For the main part of the functionality, you need to use **[`ngModelController`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)**'s `$formatters` and `$parsers` properties to register listeners to handle the changes in `$modelValue` and `$viewValue` respectively.

1. When the `$modelValue` changes, you need to filter it using the `currency` filter before displaying it to the view.
2. When the `$viewValue` changes, you need to convert it to a number (I thought it makes more sense to store the model value as number, not as a formatted string), filter that number through the `currency` filter and update the `$viewValue` (if necessary).

That is not particularly difficult. The tricky part is that updating the element's value, moves the cursor at the end, so you need to manually re-position the caret.

My attempt resulted in the following Directive Definition Object

```
{
  restrict: 'A',
  require: 'ngModel',
  link: function postLink(scope, elem, attrs, modelCtrl) {    
    modelCtrl.$formatters.push(filterFunc);
    modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (newViewValue) {
      var newModelValue = toNumber(newViewValue);
      modelCtrl.$viewValue = filterFunc(newModelValue);
      var pos = getCaretPosition(elem[0]);
      elem.val(modelCtrl.$viewValue);
      var newPos = pos + modelCtrl.$viewValue.length -
                         newViewValue.length;
      setCaretPosition(elem[0], newPos);
      return newModelValue;
    });
  }
};
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/xKrYp/)**. It's not perfect, but it's a good start.
BTW, I "borrowed" the `get/setCaretPosition()` functions from AngularUI's **[`uiMask`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-utils/blob/master/modules/mask/mask.js)** directive.

Comment: Thanks now I have a much better understanding on what I should do. I will try your solution. But the demo is only taking single digit values like $2.00 etc. I have to manually move the cursor before the decimal point and then type again to enter more digits. Please have a look. I am using latest version of Chrome.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I can enter any number (e.g.: for `$2,123.00` I place the cursor before the decimal separator and type `2`, `1`, `2`, `3`). What exactly do you mean ? (I am also using lastest version of Chrome on Windows.)

Comment: Yes, if I place the cursor before the decimal separator, it works perfectly. But my textbox will initially be blank and I will start typing from blank. In your demo, can I start from blank value? Thanks.

Comment: Everything is possible. You just need to implement it :) Check out my updated fiddle. Like I said, it is not a final solution, but it is a very good stating point. But you will have to modify it according to your specific requirements. (Please, do not forget to access the answer if it helped you solve your problem.)

Comment: Yes, everything is possible with different logic. I was just saying that the last demo was not working as per the normal requirements. But this one is better. I will modify this one also as I do not need the decimal values and round the amount to nearest 100s multiple. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi, Just found out that this code has some issues in Safari 5.1.7 on Windows. I have not checked latest Safari on Mac. The cursor position goes to 1 left position as you type. And when I try to debug the code in Safari Web Inspector, as soon as I reach inside setCaretPosition() function, my Safari reloads the page ! Please see if you get time to have a look on Safari.

Comment: Hi @ExpertSystem, I liked your approach quite a lot! Just one question though, why setting the $viewValue doesn't already updates the inputbox?  (As we have to change the element to persist the changes) Is it because we are on the parsers and there's no access or something like that? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @RafaelMerlin: That is how things work :) Assigning a new value to the `$viewValue` does not automatically set the element's value. Normally, you'd call `$render()`, but this is a special case, because we want to capture and reset the caret position, so we have to make it manually (or overwrite the controller's `$render()` method).

Comment: Isn't this backwards: "var newPos = pos + modelCtrl.$viewValue.length - newViewValue.length;"

Shouldn't it be: var newPos = pos +  newViewValue.length - modelCtrl.$viewValue.length; ?

Comment: @WilliamNeely, this implementation is too simplistice to account for all cases. The current implementation accounts for cases where `filterFunc` will prepend stuff (e.g. currency symbol) to the viewValue, but this is not always the case. Keep in mind this is just a POC, not a full-blown solution.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the [fcsa-number](https://github.com/FCSAmericaDev/angular-fcsa-number) directive that provides this for you automatically. It's as easy as adding the `fcsa-number` attribute to the input element.

```
<input type="text" fcsa-number />
```

And [here is a demo](http://embed.plnkr.co/rsP4CtMrMmkaFrQETMmZ/preview)

The source code and documentation is available on GitHub: https://github.com/FCSAmericaDev/angular-fcsa-number

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem when try to build a custom currency directive. So, after check many ways to solve I found the [angular-input-masks](https://github.com/assisrafael/angular-input-masks) directives.

Support bower for a quick installation and to use just have to add the ui-money-mask attribute on a input text element:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="money" ui-money-mask>
```

Also support min and max values validation.

Comment: Only issue with angular-input-masks is that it doesn't auto adjust cursor, as well as not supporting dynamic $locale being set.

Comment: Buggy solution.