# Using a custom currency field on numerical input in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, input, currency, formatter

I am using the currency filter shown in the "best answer" in this thread:  [Apply currency filter to the input field in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24615452/apply-currency-filter-to-the-input-field-in-angularjs)

The problem is, I also need the input field to be numerical only, i.e. type="number".  It works perfectly with type="text", but when I try to combine the two, the input disappears when the textbox loses focus.

```
<div class="table-cell">
    <div class="field-label table-cell">Estimated Yearly<br />Savings</div>
    <input ng-model="model.yearlySavings" type="number" format="currency">
</div>
```

JS:

```
mainModule.directive('format', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
return {
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
        if (!ctrl) return;

        ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function (a) {
            return $filter(attrs.format)(ctrl.$modelValue)
        });

        elem.bind('blur', function (event) {
            var plainNumber = elem.val().replace(/[^\d|\-+|\.+]/g, '');
            elem.val($filter(attrs.format)(plainNumber));
        });
    }
};
}]);
```

Note:  I would have commented in that thread, but I don't have enough "rep" to leave a comment...

Comment: This filter formats the input to a string. If you change the type of the input to number all you are saying is that the input field must expect a number, but by applying this filter you change the value of that field to a string which cannot be typecasted  to a number as it contains $ and ','. Is there any particular reason you want it to be a number?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a custom formatter from another SO thread: [AngularJS - How to apply currency filter on textbox as I type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23779574/angularjs-how-to-apply-currency-filter-on-textbox-as-i-type)

The directive is called fcsa-number: https://github.com/FCSAmericaDev/angular-fcsa-number

It took some finesse, but I got it working like this:

```
<input ng-model="model.yearlySavings" name="ys" type="text" 
    ng-class="{ 'error': formName.ys.$invalid }" fcsa-number="{ prepend: '$', preventInvalidInput: true, maxDecimals: 2 }">
```

The "ng-class" bit is used to dynamically style the border to red when the element listed (in this case "yearlySavings" aka "ys") is invalid.  In this example, it prepends my input with "$", it prevents invalid input from being entered at all (like regular text characters), and it sets the maximum decimals to 2.  Oddly enough, it does not prevent 3+ decimals from being entered like I would expect (like the regular text characters), but it does invalidate the element with more than 2.

Answer (score 0):

Create directive as below

HTML

```
  <div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
      {{amount}}
      <input format-to-currency amount="amount">
    </div>
  </div>
```

JS

```
  angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.ampunt = 2;
    })
    .directive('formatToCurrency', function($filter) {
      return {
        scope: {
          amount: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
          el.val($filter('currency')(scope.amount));

          el.bind('focus', function() {
            el.val(scope.amount);
          });

          el.bind('input', function() {
            scope.amount = el.val();
            scope.$apply();
          });

          el.bind('blur', function() {
            el.val($filter('currency')(scope.amount));
          });
        }
      }
    });
```

link http://jsfiddle.net/moL8ztrw/7/